# Method using Character.isDigit() Returns false for everything

Tags: java, string, numeric

```
public boolean isANumber (String s)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   {
      if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)));
      {
        return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

I got this method from Apache Commons Lang and edited it a bit to be shorter. Whether the input is a letter or a digit, the output is always false. Could anyone tell me why please? :)

Thanks in advance,

A.Nur

Comment: watch your semicolons. And by that i mean get rid of the semi colon at the end of your if statement

Comment: if-block has no effect in your code as semicolon simply presents and you are returning false always in { } block statement. Remove the semicolon, it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected code

```
public boolean isANumber (String s)  
{
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   {
      if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
      {
        return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

That is a good argument for putting the brace at the end of the line, instead of at the beginning of the following line.

Comment: Ah, I see. I put a semicolon in the wrong place. Thanks so much!